# How to find the number of possibilities for a string of 20 numbers where 3 of the numbers have been changed at random

Tags: probability

Say I have a string of 20 numbers and 3 of them have been changed at random. And I am using the original string to find the new one. What are the number of possibilities if I try to brute force the answer. (trying one changed number(0-9 on each), then two(two 0-9 at the same time), and then three)

I am looking for a formula where L = number of characters in string(20), C = number of possible characters(10, numbers 0-9), R = number of characters changed at random(3)

I am having trouble with my calculations giving me a higher number of possibilities than the number string could have. I was using (C-1)(L)x(C-1)(L-1)x(C-1)(L-2) for three random numbers where L goes down one for each added random number.

Comment: Please edit for clarity.  What does it mean to "try one changed number"?  Suppose had a $2$ character string.  How would you solve the problem in that case?

Comment: trying 0-9 on the first, then 0-9 on the second

Comment: So...what purpose does the original string serve?

Comment: a password longer than can be remembered and be safely written down by having part of it changed

Comment: Sorry, this is not clear at all.  The problem calls for a numerical solution.  Is the answer for the length $2$ case $10^2=100$?  Something else?  In that case, I assume the original sequence is irrelevant (since it is possible to change all the characters), but I actually have no idea.

Comment: what is the number of possibilities if only three numbers changed.

Comment: Choose which three positions are candidates for who might have been changed.  Choose what they changed into.  $\binom{L}{R}\cdot (C-1)^R$.  You made an error with multiplying by $L\times (L-1)\times (L-2)$ because it does not matter what order we chose our candidates in... just what collection of candidates they were.